# Jquery scroll to appear mobile view/media queries

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, media-queries, jquery-scrollable

Im using the below jquery function to make items appear one after the other when scrolling on a website (http://pitchandtoss.co.uk/ourstory.html) it works great however when viewed on a mobile it doesn't work properly at all because obviously the amount of pixels change on the smaller screen. Is there anything I can add like a media query maybe to change the amount of pixels on the scroll function when viewed on a mobile? thanks in advance.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $("#mydiv:visible").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#mydiv:hidden").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Umm, why doesn't it work. Your code is set to show the div if the scroll is anything larger than 0, so basically on scroll. How is that different on smaller devices? If you have multiple divs, as shown in your example, you can set your check number (in your example 0) to that divs location vertically.  See http://api.jquery.com/position/ or http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Hi Leeish, the code was just an example of what I used, the actual ones I used were set to various pixel heights of 70, 90, 100 etc.. for each div so they appear one after the other but on a smaller screen it doesn't come out the same at all, are you suggesting I change the numbers to the fixed co ordinate of the div? Sorry if this is what you were trying to say I didnt know you could do that. Thanks again.

Comment: So yeah. During your scroll event, just get the position of those divs. I think you want to use `offset`, but you may wany to use `position.` One is based on the window and the other off the parent. Either way, you can compare that value to the scroll location and show/hide at will.